# Can I just run OVA file, without "importing" it into VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, sage, appliance

I have downloaded Sage 6.3 for Windows and it is provided in OVA format. It is [said in manual](http://wiki.sagemath.org/SageAppliance#Start_VirtualBox), that to run Sage, one should:

> First, start VirtualBox. To start the Sage notebook server, power on
>   Sage-x.y.z by selecting it and clicking 'Start'. (This may take
>   awhile. You may see some warning messages you can safely ignore.)

I don't understand, what does "power on" verb mean.

If I double click this file in File Explorer, it starting an operation, called "import":

[image]

Looks like it goes to create new virtual machine from the given OVA file.

Can I just RUN this OVA file without creating any entries anywhere and importing something to somewhere? Was it intended to be so?

Or the only operation available for OVA file is "importing"?

Answer (score 4):

The only Virtualbox operation for an OVA file is to import it.  An OVA file is actually just a compressed and zipped folder.  I believe it used the gzip compression algorithm.  What this means is you can actually unzip an OVA file and access the vmdk file directly.  The "Import" command in Virtualbox simply unzips the OVA, adds the VMDK to the Virtual Media Manager, and imports the configurations.

To answer your question directly, you want the "Import" function, then once the VM has been imported, you can "Power On" the VM and log in.